# How does this link sharing work?

Tags: support, badges, hyperlinks

Recently when upvoting questions I frequently get this small pop-up offering me to share the link to get a badge. That's all nice and good but how and where do I do this? All I got is an url like this: [When you King's Court a King's Court, when must you pick the three target cards?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/936/174)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 174 is your user ID, the 936 the question ID.

If you are using this link, the traffic generated with it counts to the announcer, booster and publicist badges.

You can use the link on another site to draw attention to a certain question or answer.

Comment: it was discussed in this blog post, too: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/